# Set up airflow to work using a postgres replicated environment

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I have a postgres instance that is available in two servers. The architecture is master /standby and the standby instance is cold. Meaning I need to manually log into the server and perform the switch over from standby to master when the master is not available.

Since only the master accepts writes, I have airflow installed currently in one server, however the master can become the standby one day when the switch over happens.

I was thinking about installing airflow on both servers, define the metadata database connection as the current master and implement a sensor on one of of the servers that turns on all dags when the sensor detects the primary is not available anymore. However I'm not quite sure this is the right procedure because when this happens the metadata dB will not be available anyway. So I'm wondering what is the best solution here in an architecture like that?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is one endpoint for the application. The basic PostgreSQL architecture does not offer that solution. Yet, with the 3rd party tools you can achieve what you want. The building that architecture requires time and resources.

The first component(s) : etcd - patroni - PostgreSQL cluster to automate the cluster, and most importantly(in your case) provides APIs for HAProxy -> https://umuttechin.medium.com/postgresql-etcd-patroni-cluster-3215abd4b106 .

The second components: keepalived - HAProxy provides single endpoint to the application, so in case of switchover/failover the application doesn' t need any manuel intervention -> https://jfrog.com/community/devops/highly-available-postgresql-cluster-using-patroni-and-haproxy/ .